# gh-pages deletes my source files from the master branch

Tags: create-react-app, github-pages

I followed the instructions at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages and noticed that the command `gh-pages -b master -d build` replaced the contents of my working directory with the contents of the `build` folder and committed these changes to the `master` branch. This works as advertised to publish my React app at ***myusername*.github.io**, but it makes it impossible to make further changes to the source files since they are no longer available in the working directory.

I understand that GitHub *project* pages work differently than GitHub user pages (they allow the application to be published from the `gh-pages` branch rather than `master`). So, do I have to move my code to a new project repository or is there a way to accomplish the same thing using my existing user repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain your repositories code on the `master` branch by changing the repository settings on Github, for Github Pages, use the `/root` directory and select a new branch other than master, then, also change your deploy script.

Optionally, for a custom domain built using `create-react-app`, you will need to and a CNAME file to the your apps `public` directory.

Github Pages Settings:

[Github Pages settings using branch named production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE0k8.png)

Add optional CNAME file:

[Add CNAME file to public directory for custom domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWPcz.png)

Change the script to point to the new branch. In your package.json file update `master` to the name of your new branch.

Change:

`"deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",`

to:

`"deploy": "gh-pages -b production -d build",`

Where `production` is the name of your new branch.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to move the code. Simply create a new branch called `source` (or `dev`, or whatever you want to call it) from the commit just before gh-pages' first "Update" commit, and use that branch, rather than `master`, to continue development.

[image]